# RoR- Show page not showing user's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to bring a list of Users that a "request" has been accepted for a user to select from. I set up the collection and what is showing up on the view page is either the user id when I put `:user_id` or its shows `<User:0x007fbdrf252a60>` when i put in `user`. I tried putting in `:name` but it returns a "undefined method name" error.

Currently my form looks like:

```
<%= form_for :event_logs, url: event_logs_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@user_event_log, :id, :name ) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, :value => @event.id %>
  <%= f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller for the show its:

```
@user_event_log = RequestLog.usr_req_by current_user
```

The `user_req_by` in the model is: `scope :usr_req_by, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id) }`

If more information is needed I'm more than happy to add it. Thank you

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many  :request_logs, dependent: :destroy

  acts_as_messageable

  def first_name
    self.name.split.first
  end

  def last_name
    self.name.split.last
  end
end
```

Request Log Model:

```
class RequestLog < ApplicationRecord

  enum status: { accepted: 0, rejected: 1 }

  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :request, optional: true

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :request_id, presence: true

  scope :usr_req_by, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id) }

  scope :req_itp, ->(requests) { where(request_id: requests) }


end
```

Comment: can you paste what's in `RequestLog` and `User` models?

Comment: Added it with the last edit

Comment: Have you tried in a console: `RequestLog.usr_req_by(User.find(x))` where x is your user id (or just `User.last`) to narrow it down? Does the scope work? Does it select correct the RequestLog(s)?

Comment: @FrederikSpang Yes, it does work. It pulls up the request logs.

Answer (score 0):

The collection iterated over, is a collection of `RequestLog`. So when you use `:name` in `options_from_collection_for_select`, it tries to call `.name` on a `RequestLog`.

I suppose you want the users name there? If so, you can add a helper method to `RequestLog`

```
def user_name
  return user.name
end
```

and use :user_name in the view.

Another option, is to pass an object, that responds to `.call` as a param, as so:

```
<%= form_for :event_logs, url: event_logs_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@user_event_log, :id, ->(log){ log.user.name }) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, :value => @event.id %>
  <%= f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

I haven't tried this out, but I did look at the source for `options_from_collection_for_select`, that uses `value_for_collection` under the hood; Defined as

```
def value_for_collection(item, value)
  value.respond_to?(:call) ? value.call(item) : public_or_deprecated_send(item, value)
end
```

(See [Rails Source Code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb) and [apidock.com](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select))